# Why is the form tag rejecting click event?

Tags: javascript, html

What I have - when the user selects the download button they are directed to a certain site based on their device (android/iphone/desktop). I currently have it set up where it works perfectly. I am using google chrome's device toolbar to emulate the devices. However, when I put the button tag inside of the form tag, the click event does not occur. Nothing happens. When the form tag is removed, it works. How can I get around this issue but still use the form tag? Thanks

EDIT -- I've already made it so that these links are actions inside of the form tag, however that does not work either.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1'>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div>
           <form>
               <button type='submit' onclick='func();'>Download</button>
           </form>

    </div>

    </body>
    <script>
function func(){
       if (window.innerWidth >= 800 || window.innerHeight >= 600){      location.replace('aol.com'); 
    }     
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) { location.replace('yahoo.com');
     }
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){ location.replace('google.com');
       }
    }
    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: why would you want to put a button inside of a form? it is a type="submit" so its trying to submit the form - which has no action - better to lose the form and havethe buttnon be type ="button" and have the onclick event trigger directly

Comment: I think this will work: `onclick="return func();"`

Comment: @gavgrif Thing is, I want it to submit so that it goes to the server. Not just be a static click. Not sure how this works.

Comment: @AkhterAlaminFarhan That does not work

Comment: can you please put this `method="post"` in `<form>` tag.

Comment: I am getting 404 errors @AkhterAlaminFarhan

Comment: Why are you trying to go to the server? What are you using for the server?

Comment: @user3272438 so the click is tracked

Comment: Are you using php?

Comment: @user3272438 java

Comment: What exactly are you using in java?

Comment: I'd have to get that info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130913/discussion-between-user3272438-and-userlkjsflkdsvm).

Answer (score 0):

Add id in form and submit form using form id

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="aol.com">
      <button type='submit' onclick='return func();'>Download</button>
    </form>

 <script>
function func(){
       if (window.innerWidth >= 800 || window.innerHeight >= 600){      location.replace('aol.com'); 
    }     
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) { location.replace('yahoo.com');
     }
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){ location.replace('google.com');
       }
    }
    // put this line for submit form
    jQuery("#my_form").submit();

    </script>
```

I hope this will help U.

Comment: Would it possible to do without jQuery? That's what I'm trying to avoid @NitinVaghani

Comment: document.getElementById("my_form").submit();

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [form element].action() method instead of location.replace().

p.s. copy that sample into your site, because the snippset below blocks opening new site as I can see.

```js
function func(){
  var getForm = document.getElementById('form');
  if (window.innerWidth >= 800 || window.innerHeight >= 600){   
    getForm.action = 'http://aol.com';
  }     
  if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)) { 
        getForm.action = 'http://yahoo.com';
  }
  if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))){ 
        getForm.action = 'http://google.com';
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form id="form">
      <button type="submit" onclick='func()'>Download</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: that is what I originally had but the android page doesn't want to work. I might just have to use jQuery